# Sending a long string through ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to send a long string through ajax to php page that will process it and return what I need, I think that It exceeds GET capacity or something like that!
but for some reason it doesn't work

```
var string = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML; // so long text
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'read.php?string=' + string, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
    content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
   } else {
    content.innerHTML = 'loading';
   }
}
```

how can I make it works!

Comment: There's a limit on the size of a URL. Use POST if you have to send something big.

Comment: The other problem is that you need to URL-encode the string. If it contains `&` it will be cut off there.

Comment: could you show me example?

Comment: but it works with the short strings

Comment: How long are the long strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'read.php?string=' + string, true);
xhr.send();
```

with

```
var body = "string=" + encodeURIComponent(string);
xhr.open("POST", "read.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.send(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the URL-encoding problem, do:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'read.php?string=' + encodeURIComponent(string), true);
```