# Trying to send a long string to a script via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am very newbie with javascript, and the last three hours I have been trying to deal with a problem sending data via AJAX.

I am trying to send a string to a php file with a function. What this function does is to send a GET request to a php file which has a query and output an HTML; the function get the HTML and place it in "html_user_club".

```
    function userClubVotes(str_1,str_2,str_3) {
        if (str_1 == "") {
            document.getElementById("html_user_club").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("html_user_club").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET",'ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php?user_id='+str_1+'&user_to_visit='+str_2+'&following_votes='+str_3,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

It works, but only if the url is not very long. With this url it doesn't work:

ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php?user_id=13&user_to_visit=134&following_votes=1323.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.1323.134.23425.25245.42.24524.233.2344.232.

So, is there a way to send long url via AJAX?

EDIT:

Ok, so I have to send the string via POST instead of GET. I tried changing this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",'ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php?user_id='+str_1+'&user_to_visit='+str_2+'&following_votes='+str_3,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

For this:

```
var string = '?user_id='+str_1+'&user_to_visit='+str_2+'&following_votes='+str_3;
var body = "string=" + encodeURIComponent(string);
xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(body);
```

But still without result. Any clue?

EDIT_2

Another try, first two variables via GET and the last via POST:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",'ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php?user_id='+str_1+'&user_to_visit='+str_2,true);
xmlhttp.send();
var body = "string=" + encodeURIComponent(str_3);
xhr.open("POST", "ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.send(body);
```

Not success, but looks promising. Any idea? (I am trying to do something like in [Sending a long string through ajax doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159932/sending-a-long-string-through-ajax-doesnt-work)

Comment: The limit is generally 2048 characters for the querystring, modern browsers can handle a lot more. Are you sure the problem isn't your serverside code.

Comment: The code in the serverside is veery simple, `$_GET['following_votes'];`
Can't be there!

Comment: For a POST request, you want to remove the leading `?` from the data you are sending.

Comment: Hm, thats true. I updated again the question to add another option: sending two variables via GET in the url and the last via POST in the body. Not result…

Comment: Again, the size limit for a GET request in modern browsers is quite large, thousands of characters. The string you've posted is just 382 characters, shouldn't be a problem at all. Are you sure you're not just sending malformed data? There doesn't seem to be any urlencoded going on, and if you're sending anything other than just those numbers you should encode the data etc.

Comment: Also, the last few tries is clearly malformed. You're taking an entire querystring and urlencoding it, and then adding it to another key, making it something like `string=user_id=something&...`

Comment: Yes, I see… I am trying now to the original way, with the `xmlhttp.open("GET",'ajax/` etc. As str_3 has dots between numbers, I understand I have to encode the string. But `ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php?user_id='+str_1+'&user_to_visit='+str_2+'&following_votes='+encodeURIComponent(str_3)` doesn't help…

Answer (score 0):

You can send a POST request instead. So, you pass following_votes in the body of request and in .php file you get the value as `$_POST["following_votes"]`.

Comment: Ok, I just updated the question with a try via POST…

Answer (score 0):

For me, I always do ajax request with jquery ...
So in jquery, you can solve your problem with :

```
function userClubVotes(str_1,str_2,str_3) {
    if (str_1 == "") {
        document.getElementById("html_user_club").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {

       $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          url:"ajax/ajax-user-club-votes.php",
          data:{
             user_id:str_1,
             user_to_visit: str_2,
             following_votes:str_3
          },
          success:function(response){
              //handle response from the server
          },
          error:function(){
             //handle error
          }
       })
    }
}
```

And on PHP side, you just need to use :

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST["user_id"]);
var_dump($_POST["user_to_visit"]);
var_dump($_POST["following_votes"]);
```

To Post data to a script, it's better to use "POST" ( for all vars ) .

Comment: So this is an AJAX with Jquery… Mucho more clear! And I suppose I have to put the        `document.getElementById("html_user_club").innerHTML = this.responseText;` inside the `success:function(response){`…

Comment: Response is the text send by your back end . If your back end send a json object, response is an object